# What does "Sorry, that didn't make sense" mean?

Tags: meaning, american-english

What is the meaning of the phrase *Sorry, that didn't make sense*?

When I apologized to someone, she said that to me.

Comment: Usually, that's an apology (sorry) and "that didn't make sense" means that to them, "that" was not clear or they couldn't understand what was meant or intended.  It's a little hard to offer anything further without knowing the full context of the conversation.

Comment: You've used *apologise* rather than *apologize* and your tag says *american-english*... :-/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The speaker is apologizing for not understanding something that you said and is politely asking you to rephrase it (say it again but in a clearer way).

Comment: Or it could be that they are apologising for something they've said. For example I say to you 'mumble, mumble mumble'. You say 'pardon me, what did you say?'. I say 'Sorry, that didn't make sense. What I meant was jumble, jumble jumble.'

Comment: Yes @WS2 that is an alternative interpretation in general, but not an alternate interpretation to the situation that the OP asks about.